# Mockito Map type

Tags: java, junit, mockito

That's my code:

```
@Test(expected = ThirdLevelException.class) public void buildChMarginStockTest3() throws Exception{
        
    when(clhCategoryHistoryDAO.countById(anyString() , any(Date.class), any(Date.class), anyInt()))
        .thenReturn(0L);
    doThrow(new RepositoryException()).when(genericDAO).executeStoredProcedure(anyString(), anyMap());
        
    updateMatViewNInfoTradesPaiNpvIccBean.elabThirdLevel(clhCategoryLoad, envelopeBean);
        
}
```

The problem is that *genericDAO.executeStoredProcedure()* needs two parameters: a String and a Map<String, Object>. The code as it is now is not good cause has an error: *The method executeStoredProcedure(String, Map<String,Object>) in the type GenericDAO is not applicable for the arguments (String, Map<Object,Object>)*.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It doesn't work, the name of the method is not ok

Comment: Could you show us `executeStoredProcedure` signature - on my machine your code works perfectly fine - the type of anyMap() is inferred desired Map<String, Object>

Comment: `@Override
    public void executeStoredProcedure(String query, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws RepositoryException { }`

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of research I founded how to do that: instead of using *anyMap* I have to use *ArgumentMatchers.<String, Object>anyMap()*